# How to access a file from outside the Django Directory

Tags: python, django

Currently, I'm working in file `Proj/gui/apps/dashboard/views.py` . I want to import a file which is present outside the Django directory, ie `Proj/services/constants/global_variables.py`. How do I do it?

Here is my Project directory.

```
Proj
    |-- gui
    |   |-- apps
    |   |   |   |-- dashboard
    |   |   |       |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |       |-- models.py
    |   |   |       |-- tests.py
    |   |   |       |-- views.py
    |   |-- gui
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |-- settings.py
    |   |   |-- urls.py
    |   |   `-- wsgi.py
    |   |-- manage.py
    |-- service
        |-- constants
        |   |-- device_parameters.json
        |   |-- global_variables.py
        |   |-- __init__.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add /Proj/service to your `sys.path`, it'll make the `constants` package available. You'll find more infos here : http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: i tried `import sys
sys.path.append("/dogwood/service/constants")
import global_variables as gv`

Comment: It gives me `No module named global_variables`

Comment: @user1162512 you need the *full, absolute* path to the directory.

Comment: @user1162512: please read my answer and the part of the doc it links to. First point : what you need to add to sys.path is the full absolute path to the directory _containing_ your package(s) - in this case, "/absolute/path/to/whereever/is/Proj/services". Second point: this will make the `constants` package available so your import should be `from constants import global_vars`.

Comment: As a side note: global variables are evil

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Add your global variables to `settings.py`; then:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   print(settings.SOME_VAR) # where SOME_VAR is from your global_variables.py
   ```

   or, move your file to the same directory as `settings.py`, and then in the bottom of `settings.py`, add:

   ```
   try:
       import global_variables as gv
   except ImportError:
       pass
   ```

   Then, you can do:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.core.exception import ImproperlyConfigured

   if hasattr(settings, 'gv'):
       print(settings.gv.SOME_VAR)
   else:
       raise ImproperlyConfigured
   ```
2. Add the *full path* of the directory of the *module* to `sys.path`; but this is discouraged because django provides a way for having your own [custom settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings).

---

I think an example would be better here.  Suppose you want to have a custom variable `MY_VAR` and have it available to your django project.

Simply add it to `settings.py`, anywhere. I would recommend at the bottom:

```
# normal settings.py template code
# ..
# Custom settings

MY_VAR = True
```

Now anywhere you want to access that variable, import the settings helper, like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'file.html', {'x': settings.MY_VAR})
```

If you already have all your settings in another python file, step one is to *move it* to the same location as `settings.py`; then you can either do a "wild card" import (not recommended), or import it with an alias.

So if you have

```
-- my_proj
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- settings.py
   |-- urls.py
   |-- wsgi.py
   |-- my_settings.py
```

At the bottom of `settings.py` you would write this snippet; which tries to import `my_settings.py`:

```
try:
   import my_settings as cs  # cs = custom settings, but this can be anything
except ImportError:
   pass  # silently fail if the file cannot be found
```

Now, all the names in `my_settings.py` can be accessed using:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'file.html', {'x': settings.cs.MY_VAR})
```

Comment: `Add your global variables to settings.py; then:` How do I add my global_variables in settings?

Comment: Since `settings.py` is just a normal Python file, simply copy the contents of your global variables to it (and then you don't need your `global_variable.py` file anymore) or you can import it because any Python file is also a module. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings) goes into more detail on this.

Comment: Import it to settings.py file?

Comment: Importing it(global_variables) to settings.py file is my main concern. how di I import that? Thanks

Comment: I'll talk about the second case, ie all my settings are in another file. Cant I import it likewise without copying `mysettings` into the same folder as `settings.py`.

Comment: Since mysettings is in folder which is outside django directory and it is kept there handling the I/O operations as well.

Comment: You can simply open the file - copy its contents; and paste it into `settings.py`; then you don't need it anymore. This is all that's required.

Comment: I understand your point sir, but since I said that this file is handling I/O operations from backend as well, hence I would like to keep it separate from the GUI directory. Can I import it directly?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: copy-pasting is not a solution - the OP needs the same settings for django AND non-django stuff so it makes sense having them in the non-django part and importing them in django.

Comment: Yes, you can import it directly by doing point #2 (adding it to the path), and then you can import it directly into settings and that's it.